# How to make variables using parts of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make my own *chatbot* without following a tutorial. It consists of (so far) the `datetime` module, a list of the questions that the bot will accept and the code for the time. I have tried to use parts of the list to make separate variables e.g. `var1 = question_list[0:5]`. I thought this would work but I am not very good and I don't understand the error messages much.
This is the current code:

```
import datetime

current_time = datetime.datetime.now()

question_list = ["What is the time", "What's the time", "Tell me the time"
                 "What is the time?", What's the time?, "Show me the time",
                 "How is the weather looking?", "Show me the weather forecast",
                 "Weather forecast", "Weather", "Is it sunny today?", "Is it going to be sunny 
                  today?"]

name = input(str("Hello! I am your personal chatbot! What is your name?"))

Question = input(str("Hello, " + name + "! It is nice to meet you! Ask me a question"))

if Question == question_list[0:5]:
    print("The current time (GMT) is: ", end="")
    print(current_time)

#This block is the main problem, specifically if Question == question_list[0:5]:, I am not sure if I got this right anyways

elif Question != question_list:
    print("HELLO WORLD")
#I said this just for the purpose of finishing the code
```

Also I'm not sure how to type indents in stack overflow but those (I think) are all OK anyway

Comment: Please take a look in the [help] specifically about [ask] and how to provide a [mre]. If you get errors - post them so we can help. And also make sure this is the exact code you're running. Right now it has a problem with one of the strings but I can't know if it's a typo or your actual problem...

Comment: yeah sorry that was a typo because I was copying from a different computer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just use

```
if Question in question_list
```

that code will check if the input is same with one of the question_list that you make

but I suggest you use dictionary in python, so dictionary is like

```
dic_example = {key1: value1, key2:value2, key3:value3}
print(dic_example['key1'])
```

the expected result should be value1, so on with key2 and key3

so in your case, instead with list, you can make dictionary to make question and the answer, like

```
name_answer = ["My name is Miu", "I'm Miu"]
date_answer = ["now date is {0}".format(current_time), "date: {0}".format(current_time)]
question = {
  "what's your name?": name_answer,
  "what's the date?": date_answer
}

# the function
def chatbot(message):
    if message in question:
        return random.choice(question[message])
 
print(chatbot("what's your name?"))

# expected output should one of name_answer statement.
```

hope can help you out